# Using JQuery Datepicker (Elements With Duplicate IDs)

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am running into the below error when using the jquery-ui datepicker.

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'currentDay' of undefined or null reference

I have read online that this is because of html tags with duplicate IDs.  I am currently hiding/displaying the divs/inputs with the duplicate ID using the CSS property *display:none* depending on whether the user is looking at the site on a mobile device or not.  It looks like the hidden input is still "visible" to jquery when I am selecting the inputs for the datepicker using the lines of code below.

> $("#emp2startdate").datepicker();
>
> $("#emp2enddate").datepicker();

How can I completely hide html tag IDs from jquery so I am not selecting duplicate IDs?

Comment: Don't use IDs wherever it's possible. You could use any custom attribute or class name. Also the main idea of ID is ignored. ID should be the only one by page. ID should be unique by page.

Comment: CSS rule `display` influences the only visibility but not the presence of an element. If you don't see the element it doesn't mean javascript doesn't see it.

Comment: You need to remove the duplicate ids, not hide them. Change the elements to use common classes instead as that's what they were designed for; grouping elements

Comment: You will need to check if mobile with javascript, then find `$('.mobile #yourID')` or `$('.not-mobile #yourID')`

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe: `$('[id="emp2startdate"]:visible').datepicker()`

Comment: `$('[id=value]')` or `$('#id, #id')` is a work around for duplicate ids.  It should **not** be used if at all possible, and only reserved for if you are working with third party systems that control the content creation and you have no control over it.  Fixing the markup to not have duplicate ids is much more preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to avoid changing the IDs because I figured I was using them somewhere else in the code.  After some digging around, I found that the IDs of each input were not used anywhere else, so I could change them without worry.